# sense movement of muscles via electronic signals

Tags: arduino, c, biopotential

I'd like to sense when a certain muscle is contracting or releasing, for instance the movement of one finger over another.

Is there any existing work to do this with sensors / arduino / galvanic skin response?

Comment: Electronically, signals to the mussels can be monitored, but I have never heard of anything that would yield absolute position, as to whether movement has taken place.

Answer (score 3):

First, fingers don't have muscles that you can measure potentials from.  All the muscles that move fingers are in the forearm, with tendons extending into the hand to move fingers.   The anatomy is complex.  While a pro can sort things out, I wouldn't assume that you would be able to pull out enough info to differentiate between fingers.  (The thumb is a different story).

Assuming you will eventually be measuring muscle activity, which is an electromyogram, or EMG,  this is a high frequency AC signal.  It can be teased into a very rough estimate of muscle tension by rectifying it and then low pass filtering it at about 10 to 15 Hz.   You can do this in software, but you can sample much slower if you do it in hardware. It will be difficult to calibrate between different muscles. I'm not sure if the EEG shield people are talking about will let you sample fast enough for raw EMG before rectification and filtering.

I'd go another route, like a glove with flexiforce sensors.

Comment: why do I need to rectify? I'm unfamiliar with the concept above what I can understand from roughly reading Wikipedia.

Comment: @lollercoaster -- if you don't rectify, the output of low-pass filtering an AC signal is zero.

Answer (score 1):

An EEG, such as this [Arduino friendly device at Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-EEG-and-ECG-Circuit/) will have plenty of sensitivity for your purpose. Just place a pair of electrodes near the muscle you're interested in.

Comment: That link eventually pointed me to a good source of
TD-985XX Panel Mount Jacks,which I've been looking for forever!!  +1

Answer (score 0):

"Myo" is in preorder right now; it will have an SDK but I don't know whether you can use it with an Arduino.

https://www.thalmic.com/en/myo/

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of good books on the subject of biophysical instrumentation:

[Handbook of Biomedical Instrumentation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070473552)

[Biophysical Measurements](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000O2Z3Y2)